# How can the numpy computing sequence influence the result?

Tags: numpy

why the following two lines of code compute the same thing ,but I get the different results.

```
kernel1 = np.diag(np.exp(-scale*eigen_values))
kernel2 = np.exp(-scale*np.diag(eigen_values))
```

the

```
np.all(kernel1==kernel2)
```

output

```
False
```

Comment: the eigen is a ndarray of shape (n,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the values!  Then you'll see the problem: when given a 1-d array, [`numpy.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) creates a 2-d array with zeros in the off-diagonal positions.  In `kernel1`, you do `diag` last, so the off-diagonal values are 0.  In `kernel2`, you apply `exp` *after* `diag`, and `exp(0)` is 1, so in `kernel2`, the off-diagonal terms are all 1.  (Remember that [`numpy.exp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) is applied element-wise; it is not the matrix exponential.)

```
In [19]: eigen_values = np.array([1, 0.5, 0.1])

In [20]: scale = 1.0

In [21]: np.diag(np.exp(-scale*eigen_values))
Out[21]: 
array([[0.36787944, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.60653066, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.90483742]])

In [22]: np.exp(-scale*np.diag(eigen_values))
Out[22]: 
array([[0.36787944, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.60653066, 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 0.90483742]])
```